# How to access sfdc.userId in Test Classes for Chatter tab

Tags: chatter

I have created a Chatter sub tab and need to write test class for it. In the test class I need to access `sfdc.userId` to identify if I'm viewing my profile or someone else's profile.

In the Controller, I'm getting sfdc.userId from URL using below mentioned line:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.userId');
```

Now how can I get or set `sfdc.userid` in my test class. The current test class code is given below. The put method does not work, as `sfdc.userid` is null in controller.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.MyChatterSubTabPage; 
pageRef.getParameters().put('sfdc.userId',u.Id);
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

MyChatterSubTabPage t = new MyChatterSubTabPage(new ApexPages.StandardController(u));
```

---

The documentation for `sfdc.userid` is given below:

> The profile will always pass sfdc.userId=[UserId] to all child tab pages excluding Web tabs, which require configuration by the administrator due to security constraints. This is the ID of the profile being viewed, not the ID of the person viewing the profile.

Link: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_profile_tabs_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that u.Id isn't null?

Comment: yes Ketih.. The below mentioned system.debug statement returns null....              pageRef.getParameters().put('sfdc.userId',u.Id);
       pageRef.getParameters().put('abc','value abc');
       test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);  
system.debug('_--------- in  Test class 1 '+ ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.userId'));

Comment: I did not insert the user and hence it was coming up as NULL.... Thanks Keith, I read your asnwer again and ensured that U.id is not null and it resolved the problem. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I did not get a way to tag Keith's answer as resolved or best answer. Hence tagging this as resolved. keith suggestion to ensure that U.id is not null worked. Thanks again Keith.